# I don't know why Wordpress worked follow that way

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a problem with a Wordpress permalink.

These are my steps to show the problem:

1) in admin > pages: I create new page call "**GoodMorning**" and I have slug "**goodmorning**", on frontend, I run **://my_domain/goodmorning** will show the content of this page

2) Now, I run **://my_domain/find-me/goodmorning** it will auto redirect to **://my_domain/goodmorning**

**/find-me/** : this is any name and this text does not exist on wordpress slug, category, page, post, ....

Please let me know why. I want it to show a 404 page when I run **://my_domain/find-me/goodmorning**.

Thanks All.

Comment: Create a `post type` -> `Find Me` and the create a `post` -> `Good Morning`. Now this post will have`://my_domain/find-me/goodmorning` as URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this (to `functions.php`) should stop that redirect.

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

If you look at the documentation for `redirect_canonical` [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_canonical):

> Will also attempt to find the correct link when a user enters a URL that does not exist based on exact WordPress query. Will instead try to parse the URL or query in an attempt to figure the correct page to go to.

I assume that's what you're trying to prevent based on your question.

If you need the other functionality of `redirect_canonical` you can just cancel the redirect by returning `false` to this filter, like so:

```
add_filter('redirect_canonical', '__return_false');
```

You need to flush your permalinks configuration afterwards:

1. In the main menu find "Settings > Permalinks".
2. Scroll down if needed and click "Save Changes".
3. Rewrite rules and permalinks are flushed.

Comment: Correct Answer !  :D

Comment: fantastic, this is all my need. Thank you very much.